# How to check percentage of an image covered by text?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, opencv, image-processing

Is there any way to programmatically calculate what percentage of an image is covered by text? I'm trying to do this in either node.js or python but can't seem to find anything that does this - I've found quite a few libraries that let you analyze the text and/or change the image attributes themselves (tesseract looked promising initially), but nothing gives me back an area or amount - usually just the text itself. Any ideas would be appreciated, sorry about the lack of code I've tried but can't find anything about this anywhere.

Comment: Is the text in the same div as the image? Does the image take up the entire div. Could you share a sample HTML page of what you're trying to calculate?

Comment: That's a pretty complex task. Perhaps openCV + Tesseract to detect text, create new blank image of same size and overlay said text with specific pixel value, count number of this value in new image?

Comment: @SarahJessica the image isn't in a div, I'd just be giving the function an image URL

Comment: @Gavin I was thinking of doing something similar but from what I can see tesseract doesn't actually give you any size information, so how would the pixels be calculated in a non-arbitrary way? It needs to account for differences in font type as well

Comment: @Jul I'm not super familiar with how Tesseract works with OpenCV, but it you can get the contours used to return the bounding boxes it should be trivial to add up the `contourAreas` up for each character.

Comment: Can you post some example pictures?

Comment: Here's an idea: Convert to grayscale, adaptive threshold, remove non-text contours using a maximum threshold value to isolate only text on the binary mask, calculate number of white pixels on mask to determine percentage of text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a potential approach using thresholding + contour filtering with OpenCV:

- Convert image to grayscale and adaptive threshold
- Find contours and filter using a defined threshold to remove all non-text contours
- Draw non-text contours onto a mask and bitwise-xor to only obtain text
- Calculate percentage of text pixels

---

Since you did not provide input images, I will use this example image from a textbook. Note some of the text is colored and there is a picture to simulate a normal image with text.

[image]

We begin by converting the image to grayscale and adaptive threshold with `cv2.adaptiveThreshold()` to obtain a binary image.

```
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)
```

Next we find contours using `cv2.findContours()` and filter using contour area with `cv2.contourArea()`. We define a `picture_threshold` value which defines the threshold of a non-text contour. Essentially this value determines that if a contour is too large, it must be a picture so we want to filter these contours out of our image. In this case, we define a non-text contour as any contour that is greater than `5%` of the image size. This is a decent assumption as a single word will not be greater than `1%` of the entire image area (unless its a logo but lets assume just normal text).

Thresholded binary image (left) and filtered non-text contours on a mask (right)

[image]
[image]

```
mask = thresh.copy()
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

picture_threshold = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * .05
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < picture_threshold:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)
```

To remove the undesired contours, we perform a bitwise-xor operation to obtain our filtered image with only text. This is the image we will calculate the percentage of text pixels on.

[image]

```
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(thresh, mask)
```

Since we have isolated only text contours on the image, we simply count the number of white pixels on the image with `cv2.countNonZero()`. We can obtain the percentage of text pixels by dividing with the image's area. Here's the result:

> Percentage: 13.15%

```
text_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(result)
percentage = (text_pixels / (image.shape[0] * image.shape[1])) * 100
print('Percentage: {:.2f}%'.format(percentage))
```

---

Full code for completeness

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,3)

mask = thresh.copy()
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])

picture_threshold = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1] * .05
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < picture_threshold:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
result = cv2.bitwise_xor(thresh, mask)

text_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(result)
percentage = (text_pixels / (image.shape[0] * image.shape[1])) * 100
print('Percentage: {:.2f}%'.format(percentage))

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I upvote your answer. However, I wonder what is the practical application for this kind of task?

Comment: Not sure what OP is planning to do but it can come into play when analyzing text in advertisement images. Apparently images with less than 20% text perform better. Take look at [facebook text in ad images](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/980593475366490?id=1240182842783684). Facebook already implemented this [tool to determine how much text is in an ad image](https://www.facebook.com/ads/tools/text_overlay)

Comment: wow. first time heard of it. Look like FB tool is more complicated than this one.

Comment: @nathancy this is awesome, thanks! and yes it's to ensure images don't get rejected by Facebook's 20% text rule