# OpenCV Extract Original image according to the mask obtained?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a project in which I want to extract image from the original image by using Mask that I am obtain. I used the code to obtain the mask ([How to check percentage of an image covered by text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876353/how-to-check-percentage-of-an-image-covered-by-text)) So by applying the given code I am obtaining 2 images one is result and mask image by using that I want to extract/crop from the original image separately and save it for further work.

First I thought of subtracting them but there is dimension problem than I thought of bounding box but it was not giving me the replica of the images that I am getting as mask and result on the original image.

Result image getting from the code:

[image]

Mask image getting from the code:

[image]

[image: Original image]

Comment: Please explain by posting some images and the code you tried

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Put your mask in the alpha channel of the image to make the masked out regions transparent.